# Ajax request, page not found 404, when "http://" is in the sender serialized data

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization, http-status-code-404

I have an really strange issue. I have a form with a lot of fields, this form is used to add some data in my db, I use jquery to seriallize that like this

`var data = $('#form_id').serialize();`

and this is my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://someurl.com/save',
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function() {
        Loading('save');
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        LoadingDone();
        note(XMLHttpRequest.responseText, true, 'error');
    },      
    success: function(data) {
        handler('/', data);
    },
    async: true
});
```

Evrithing works perfect when I'm on my localhost which is xampp, but when is online, on some linux hosting, and I type a "http://" in a input field, and send the data, ajax goes into `error:` callback with message Page Not Found 404. I tried to workaround first I removed the `data` variable which I pass and everything went well, so I think the problem is that 'http://' is in the `data`. The Question is why in windows with xampp is working well? Thanks for any help.

Comment: There's nothing about AJAX that would cause that automatically. It has to have something to do with how the server script processes the parameters, or how the callback function is using the response.

Comment: Check the Network tab of Developer Tools to see what URL the AJAX is being sent to, and what the response contains. Are there any redirects involved in this?

Comment: This is the other strange thing, it seems that can't access the server at all, I put die('END'); in http://someurl.com/save and when I access it trough url is working when I try with ajax and there is a http:// in some of my inputs boom in error console, http://someurl.com/save - page not found. Replace, data with {} and is ok.

Comment: I think that something is not escaped properly, but how I can check?

Comment: jQuery automatically encodes everything properly when you call `serialize`. You need to show more code, so we can see what you're doing with the parameters.

Comment: Maybe your host blocks posted data with `http://` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Very often, the urls change when you are deploying your solution to real environment instead of your local machine.

What I normally do to fix it, is to create a function like this to calculate the real url:

```
function startURL()
{

  var resultat = '/';

  if ($(location).attr('hostname') == 'localhost') {
    return resultat;
  }
  else
  {
    var urlActual = $(location).attr('pathname');

    for(var i=1;i<=urlActual.length-1;i++)
    {
      if (urlActual.substr(i, 1) != '/') {
        resultat += urlActual.substr(i, 1);
      }
      else { break;}

    }

    return resultat+'/';

  }
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. His problem isn't with the URL of the page, it's with a form input that happens to contain something that looks like a URL.

Comment: Yes, I see, but the fact that he's having this problem when the hosting changes may indicate that the ajax call cannot find the correct path because it changes depending on the path that the server is using.

Comment: It is (maybe) because when the http:// is present, it tries to access to an absolute path, and without it, the relative path is calculated ok... In the local environment, both are the same, but on a hosted environment... Who knows ?

Comment: But form fields have nothing to do with the URL that the AJAX request is sent to. Something in the code must be turning that form field into a URL to redirect to. And that's somehow dependent on where the script is running.

Comment: the requested url is fine I see it in networks -> headers tab in mozilla inspect it is full url http://someurl.com/save eaven when I copy and paste in the address bar I can access the controller